# Blade, Use html inside variable being passed into partial view is not being rendered

Tags: html, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I'm using a partial view to display page header, that view accepts two variables one is Icon the other is a title.
pageHeader.blade.php:

```
<div class="page-header">
<div class="row">
    <!-- Page header, center on small screens -->
    <h1 class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 text-center text-left-sm"><i class="fa {{$icon}} page-header-icon"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;{{$title}}</h1>
</div>
```

and I'm using it like so:

```
@include('zdashboard._partials.pageHeader',['icon'=>'fa-pencil','title'=>'<strong>Editing</strong>'.$center->translations()->whereLang('en')->first()->name])
```

Sometimes I like to make one word strong or italic like the example above but, blade engine won't render the HTML tags I'm typing as part of `title` variable (the output like the photo down).

So is there any idea how to solve this? Am I doing it!

wrong?

[The output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t1AGV.png)

Answer (score 79, accepted):

By default in Laravel 5 `{{ $title }}` construction wil be escaped.

If you don't want the data to be escaped, you may use the following syntax:

```
{!! $title !!}
```

Read more about Blade control structures: http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/templates#other-blade-control-structures

Comment: Thanks, for sure I'm using it, but I don't know why in my mind I'm escaping only JS things :S

Comment: Nice! its helped me alot

Answer (score -1):

### view

```
@if(Session::has('success'))
    <div class="alert alert-success">
     {!! Session::get('success')!!}  
    </div>
@endif
```

### Controller

```
public function store(Request $request)
 {
   $this->validate($request, [
            'product_code' => 'required|unique:products',
            'product_name' => 'required',
            'description' => 'required',
            'price' => 'required',
            'brand_id' => 'required',
            'category_id' => 'required',
        ]);
        $product = Product::create([
            'product_code' => $request->input('product_code'),
            'product_name' => $request->input('product_name'),
            'description' => $request->input('description'),
            'price' => $request->input('price'),
            'brand_id' => $request->input('brand_id'),
            'category_id' => $request->input('category_id'),
        ]);
        return redirect()->route('products.index')->with('success', 
        "The product <strong>".$product->product_name."</strong> has successfully been created.");
    }
```

Comment: Please be sure to add appropriate comments and explanations with answers. Answers that are just code are not very helpful.